# Why would imap jk <Esc> result in sometimes inserting jk instead of Escaping?

Tags: vim

I have `imap jk <esc>` in my `.vimrc`. Recently vim has started inserting jk into the document when I type jk in insert mode, rather than escaping to normal mode as it should. It happens rarely enough to be hard to reproduce, but often enough to be quite frustrating.

I've recently installed a couple plugins, `w0rp/ale` and `SirVer/ultisnips`, so I suspect they may be the cause, but I have difficulty reproducing the issue on demand making it hard to test.

What steps should I take to track down the cause of this problem?

Comment: What does `:set timeoutlen?` print?

Comment: I use innoremap jk <esc>

Answer (score -1):

I disabled plugins one by one and found that it was the YouCompleteMe plugin causing this issue.